# I need to create a process which will monitor selenium execution and will click on popups if arrives during execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to create a process which will monitor selenium execution and will click on popups if arrives during execution.

Suppose my selenium automation script is currently in execution, suddenly some popup comes and I need to handle the popup. What should I do?

In my project, all our scripts are ready so no chance in modifying in those. So I need to create separate thread which will monitor Selenium script execution and handles the pop up.

Please suggest what can be done in this regards.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Java supports the creation of dynamic proxy classes and instances. Proxy objects are useful in many situations.

ElementProxy class which implements this interface. Basically, the proxy’s invoke method would be called first before the actual method is invoked. As our idea was to call checkForPopupAndKill before invoking any action on a WebElement, this could be the right place to include the checkForPopupAndKill method.

public class ElementProxy implements InvocationHandler {

```
private final WebElement element;

public ElementProxy(WebElement element) {
    this.element = element;
}

@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    //before invoking actual method check for the popup
    this.checkForPopupAndKill();
    //at this point, popup would have been closed if it had appeared. element action can be called safely now.
    Object result = method.invoke(element, args);
    return result;
}

private void checkForPopupAndKill() {
    if (popup.isDisplayed()) {
        System.out.println("You damn popup, you appearded again!!?? I am gonna kill you now!!");
        popup.close();
    }
}
```

}

Need to wrap our regular WebElement with this proxy object. We basically need a class which has a method to accept a WebElement and returns the WebElement with some wrapper.

public class ElementGuard {

```
public static WebElement guard(WebElement element) {
    ElementProxy proxy = new ElementProxy(element);
    WebElement wrappdElement = (WebElement) Proxy.newProxyInstance(ElementProxy.class.getClassLoader(),
                                                                   new Class[] { WebElement.class },
                                                                   proxy);
    return wrappdElement;
}
```

}